# Звонок с WhatsApp из андроид приложения, не срабатывает первый раз

Tags: android, whatsapp, android-cursor

Просмотрел похожие темы, но решить проблему не помогло. Окно с WhatsApp откроется только после 2 нажатия на кнопку, первый раз при нажатии записывается только номер в контакты, если его нет. При дебаге, при первом нажатии обнаружил что не могу зайти в блок `while` т.к. cursor.moveToNext() всегда false при первом нажатии в методе `getUriFromPhoneNumber`, а когда нажимаю 2 раз и все последующие разы - работает отлично, пожалуйста подскажите где я мог ошибиться.

```
public static void callWhatsApp(String phoneNumber, String name, Activity activity) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri = getUriFromPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, activity.getApplicationContext(), name, activity);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call");
        intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }

    private static Uri getUriFromPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber, Context context, String name, Activity activity) {
        Uri uri = null;
        String contactId = getContactIdByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, context);
        // check for exist phone number
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(contactId)) {
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.Data._ID},
                    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                    new String[]{"vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call", contactId}, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                // here in the first time equals false and not will work, need fix
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data._ID));
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
                        uri = Uri.parse(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI + "/" + id);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
        } else {
            addToContactsNewNumber(phoneNumber, name, activity);
        }
        return uri;
    }

    // find phone number in contacts
    private static String getContactIdByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber, Context context) {
                ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
                String contactId = null;
                Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
                String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID};
                Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                if (cursor != null) {
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));
                    }
                    cursor.close();
        }
        return contactId;
    }

    private static void addToContactsNewNumber(String number, String name, Activity activity) {
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
        int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
                ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                .build());
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name).build());
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.
                newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, number)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                .build());
        try {
            activity.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
            callWhatsApp(number, name, activity);
        } catch (RemoteException | OperationApplicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Ни один способ не помог, уже теряю надежду...

Comment: Мне не нравится `activity.getApplicationContext()` - контекст приложения иногда дает странные фокусы. Попробуйте просто `activity` в качестве контекста

Comment: попробуйте добавить `cursor.moveToFirst();` перед циклом.

Comment: если добавить cursor.moveToFirst() то вообще не сработает, менял контекст, тоже не помогло...

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что проблема в том, что вы пользуетесь недокументированными возможностями. А именно сомнение вызывает mime тип: `vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call`, при первом вызове его нет, соответственно вы врукопашную записываете его в контакт, естественно при втором вызове он появляется и поэтому у вас все срабатывает.

В [манифесте Whatsapp](https://gist.github.com/kimenye/eef321a2a182bd4544af) такой mime тип незадекларирован...